# How do I fix WCF "Requested Upgrade is not supported by net.tcp" error?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, net.tcp

I have an asp.net mvc 3 application running on my local IIS7. This has a reference to a WCF service that works great.

I recently added a reference to another service hosted in the same place, and I get the following error when a method is invoked:

> The requested upgrade is not supported by 'net.tcp://webdev02:15001/CommonService/Service.svc/mex'. This could
>   be due to mismatched bindings (for example security enabled on the
>   client and not on the server).

The web.config at the service has identical settings between the bindings for the first working service and the second non-working service. Same story at my client.

I'm also using my windows credentials to connect, like so:

```
svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "myname";
svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "mypass";
```

Also, I can call both services successfully using the WcfTestClient. Any thoughts as to why one would not be working for me? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So everything is configured as it should be. The problem occurred when I set my URL on the endpoint during the service instantiation on the client, I included the `/mex` at the end, like so:

`net.tcp://webdev02:15001/CommonService/Service.svc/mex`

When in fact my URL should have been:

`net.tcp://webdev02:15001/CommonService/Service.svc`

Everything works great now that I chopped off the `/mex`.

Answer (score 0):

The mex is the metadata, and (typically) doesn't require credentials to view.  I would start by looking at your service endpoint settings for the metadata (mex) exchange.

I haven't done WCF on net.tcp, but here's an example from my HTTP WCF App:

```
   <endpoint
      address=""
      binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="RequestUserName"
      contract="MyService.IContract"/> 
   <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
```

I can view the wsdl without credentials with the binding set to mexHttpBinding, while the methods are protected by having wsHttpBinding set to:

```
 <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RequestUserName">
        <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Again, I don't have direct experience with net.tcp WCF, but I believe your binding on IMetadataExchange is where to start looking.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Turns out my bindings were fine, it was an error in the URL I was setting for the endpoint. See answer for details.